# Delphi self-deleting program

Tags: windows, delphi, assembly

How do I auto-delete, my Delphi program? I tried this code:

```
procedure DeleteSelf;
var
  module : HMODULE;
  buf : array [ 0 .. MAX_PATH - 1 ] of char;
  p : ULONG;
  hKrnl32 : HMODULE;
  pExitProcess, pDeleteFile, pFreeLibrary : pointer;
begin
  module := GetModuleHandle ( nil );
  GetModuleFileName ( module, buf, sizeof ( buf ) );
  CloseHandle ( THandle ( 4 ) );
  p := ULONG ( module ) + 1;
  hKrnl32 := GetModuleHandle ( 'kernel32' );
  pExitProcess := GetProcAddress ( hKrnl32, 'ExitProcess' );
  pDeleteFile := GetProcAddress ( hKrnl32, 'DeleteFileA' );
  pFreeLibrary := GetProcAddress ( hKrnl32, 'FreeLibrary' );
  asm
    lea eax, buf
    push 0
    push 0
    push eax
    push pExitProcess
    push p
    push pDeleteFile
    push pFreeLibrary
    ret
  end;
end;
```

But it does not work, do not delete the file. My program is console. 
Thanks!

Comment: What are you actually trying to do? What's wrong with just exiting? This looks like a wayback trip to Win16.

Comment: The only way I see this possible is by calling another program (or batch file) which does this when the app exits. It's literally impossible for an app to delete its self without depending on another outside helper to do so.

Comment: So the only solution is to create a file. Bat?

Comment: Not necessarily, the only solution is to do rely on something outside of your executable to do the job for you.

Comment: The OP code is buggy. While I was fixing the code the question was closed. Evidently the question is not a duplicate, the question is about why the posted code does not work.

Comment: Your Assembly code is doing nothing anyways.  You get the procaddress, you are supposed push the proc params then CALL that address you got with GetProcAddress FYI, as others said you can't just delete your program like that.

Comment: The ComSpecMelt() function located here does work:  http://www.delphibasics.info/home/delphibasicssnippets/self-deletingfile-melting

Comment: No @Gunner, the code is correct (on systems where it was ever valid). It pushes the addresses of the functions onto the stack and then returns. Returning pops the top stack address and jumps there. Since the top address is to `FreeLibrary`, it calls `FreeLibrary` using the argument pushed in `p` and then returns. *Its* return address has been spoofed to refer to `DeleteFile`, which reads the value pushed from `eax` and "returns" to `ExitProcess`. It's a trick to avoid reading any more code from the current code segment, which goes away when calling `FreeLibrary`.

Comment: @Serg, where does this question ask why that code doesn't work? The question seems pretty clear in the first sentence.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Your code **only** will work under Windows NT and 2000. Because in these OSs the system keeps a usermode handle reference to the memory mapped file which backs the executable image on disk. **This handle always has a value 0x4** in these Windows versions.

The most effective way to delete your own exe, is creating  a child process in suspended state, inject the code to wait for the parent process (the exe to delete) , then detect when the parent process exits,  delete the parent process and finally kill the child process.

You can found more about this topic in these recommendded resources.

- [Self-deleting Executables (Techniques which allow an executable file to delete itself whilst running)](http://www.catch22.net/tuts/self-deleting-executables)
- [`Self deleting executables`](http://blogorama.nerdworks.in/comment.aspx?entryID=21) Ranju. V.